Integrating MapStruct and useIncrementalCompilation on a java project
I am working on a enterprise java project and we want to add mapstruct as a dependency. We set <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation> (it was previously set to false before adding MapStruct). We encountered some compilation related issues, but we solved them and now the project compiles, but we get runtime exceptions.
We thought about using the <incrementalExcludes>, but we are not entirely sure on how to use it or if this would solve the problem. Any ideas on how to use <incrementalExcludes>?
Thanks

I fixed your formatting for you. In the future, please look over the preview before hitting submit!

Thanks :) and sorry for the inconvenience

When you enable incremental compilation using <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>, Maven tries to optimize the build process by recompiling only the changed parts of your code.
The <incrementalExcludes> configuration allows you to exclude specific files or directories from incremental compilation.
By excluding certain files, you can ensure that they are always recompiled from scratch, avoiding any potential issues caused by incremental compilation.
Example
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <!-- Add incrementalExcludes here -->
                <incrementalExcludes>
                    <exclude>**/CarMapperImpl.java</exclude>
                    <!-- Add other exclusions if needed -->
                </incrementalExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Do you have any example on how to use ? It would definitely help! Do I need to specify the package or a path?
